# how to efficiently match two data tables in R

Tags: r, match

**Situation:**
I have a CSV file `A` with two columns `Customer ID` and `Entry date`.
`A` contains about 1.500.000 observations.

I have another CSV file `B` with a single column `Customer ID`.
`B` is a smaller subset of `A`.

**Goal:**
Since the info about their entry date is missing in table `B`, I would like to get that info from table `A` and write it all into a new table `C`.

**Current Progress:**
I've created 10 subsets S1,...,S10 from `A` and from each subset the maximum customer ID. In a `for` loop, I run through all entries of `B` and check if `B` lies within one of the subsets (via `customer ID` and `max c ID` of the subset). Once I've found a subset in which I am supposed to find the customer ID, I use the function *`which`* to look for the element of B in A.

This is awfully slow.

Isn't there another quicker way?

And which would be the best objects in R to use the CSV file as, currently, `A` is a *data Frame*, and `B` is a *large integer*.

Comment: `merge` (or even faster a data.table or dplyr join).

Comment: Duh :D   Thanks a lot - that's what I was looking for :)))

Comment: This is a precursor to a merge, but `A[A$CID %in% B, ]` will work if B is an integer, and CID is the column in A where your customer ID is. With data table, you can do an explicit "merge" with `setDT(A); setkey(A,CID); A[J(B)]`

Comment: @blueeyes0710 - I found this [data.table cheat sheet](https://s3.amazonaws.com/assets.datacamp.com/img/blog/data+table+cheat+sheet.pdf) useful when getting to learn this very powerful package

Answer (score 8):

I would use `data.table`. It is trivially easy to do this (see last command!), and very fast using what is known as a keyed join. Basically you look up entries from `b` in `a` using their common key (in your case `"Customer ID"`). As an example:

```
require(data.table)
a <- data.table(id=1:10,date=as.Date(1:10))
setkey(a,id)
b <- data.table(id=4:6)
setkey(b,id)

a[b]
#   id       date
#1:  4 2016-02-01
#2:  5 2016-02-02
#3:  6 2016-02-03
```

---

With your given example you would type this, to read in your data and do a keyed join to get the entry date for each person in table `b`:

```
a <- fread( "A.csv" )
setkey(a, "Customer ID")
b <- fread( "B.csv" )
setkey(a, "Customer ID")

c <- a[b]
```

Comment: You can also simply do `a[b, on='id']` (quite explicit besides) without using `setkey`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `data.table`'s `fread` to read in your `CSV` files:

```
library(data.table);
table_a <- fread("A.csv");  # Defaults are probably fine
table_b <- fread("B.csv");
```

Use `merge` to use the index in B to create C:

```
# Assuming the column name has an underscore instead of space
setkey(table_a, Customer_ID);
setkey(table_b, Customer_ID);

table_c <- merge(x=table_b, y=table_a, by="Customer_ID", all.x=TRUE);
```

Write the new table to CSV if desired:

```
write.csv(x=table_c, file="C.csv");
```

Comment: Blue eyes - Don't forget to set keys to the 'data.table' to enhance speed

Comment: Indeed.  `setkey` is important!